# The difference between the different methods to remove all same items from a list

Tags: java, list

I have trouble to tell the difference between the two methods, are they exactly the same thing? Thanks

```
1. @Override
   public boolean removeAllFromBasket(Item i) {
        boolean removed = false;
        while (this.items.contains(i)) {
            removed = true;
            this.items.remove(i);
        }
        return removed;
    }
2. @Override
    public boolean removeAllFromBasket(Item i) {
        while (this.items.contains(i)) {
            this.items.remove(i);
        }
        return this.items.contains(i);
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think they are the same? That might show where exactly your misunderstanding is.

Comment: Method 1) return true if item was in basket and was deleted, false otherwise (for example if this item was never in the basket) Method 2) returns always false

Comment: I understand, thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First method will return false if items do not contain item otherwise will remove all items and return true.
- Second method will remove all items and return false.